# Is $G/G'$ an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $G'=\langle [x,y] : x , y \in G\rangle $, where $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. 
I am trying to prove that $G/G'$ is an abelian group.

What I've done:
$$X\in G/G' \Rightarrow X=xG' ; x\in G$$
$$Y\in G/G' \Rightarrow Y=yG' ; y\in G$$
$$XY=(xG')(yG')=xyG'$$
$$YX=(yG')(xG')=yxG'$$

Now, I have to prove that $XY=YX$, but I don't know how to do that :(
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know that G' is a normal subgroup of G, but I don't know that it can be useful or not...

Comment: If $G'$ wer not a normal subgroup, then the quotient $G/G'$ would not be a group and your question would be meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of proving that $XY=YX$, prove that $XYX^{-1}Y^{-1}=1_{G/G'}$, to do so notice that:
$$XYX^{-1}Y^{-1}=[x,y]G'.$$

Answer (score 3):

To prove that $G/G'$ is abelian you need to show that $\forall x,y \in G$

$$(xG')(yG')=(yG')(xG') \iff xyG' = yxG' \iff x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \in G'$$

What is the definition of $G'$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$yxG'=yx(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)G'=xyG'$$